# Download file from url?

Tags: javascript

im trying do download file but without success. Im using this code but on click it open image, but i dont want to do that .. i want to download that image. Any suggestion?

```
  toDataURL(url) {
        return fetch(url).then((response) => {
                return response.blob();
            }).then(blob => {
                return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            });
    }
```

then

```
async download() {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = await toDataURL("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png");
        a.download = "myImage.png";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Comment: `window.open(url , "_blank");` is simple solution for downloading a file with url

Comment: how is this download and not open?

Comment: try to add this to your `a` element : `a.setAttribute('download','')`. Or even simpler : `a.download=''`

Comment: This question is tagged "Angular", but this is definitely not the Angular way to do something like this.

Comment: @kshetline that's true but Angular allows you to do thing in pure javascript :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an angular way, but using pure js : [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
function download(url, name) {
  fetch(url).then((response) => {
    return response.blob().then((b) => {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.setAttribute("download", name);
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(b);
      a.click();
    });
  });
}

download('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png', 'ninja.png')
```

Comment: i have problem with cross origin when i use like this

Comment: yes in console i get : Access to fetch at : https......from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: This is your server configuration that does not allow CORS

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple [`<a>` download link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp):

HTML

```
<a [href]="imageUrl" download>Download image</a>
```

component.ts

```
imageUrl:string = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png"
```

Comment: i need to call this in ts file because i dont have url i have id where i call service to get url and then do the download

Comment: @None That's why there's the "imageUrl" field in your TS that can be dynamically filled (so your link url can change whenever you want)

Comment: That's precisely why I defined the URL in the script, and not hardcoded in the HTML template. This way it's dynamic.

Comment: im getting this error : 'url' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Comment: ah, sorry, it's `href`

Comment: Strange, how are you testing it? In something like Stackblitz, or directly in your local application? Because I use this code in my Angular apps and it works, the file gets downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="data:...." target="_blank">`
OR
use downloadify