# Can you force the browser to download a file with HttpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular SPA which needs to allow the user to download some files.
I am aware you can use [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) to download the file, but this is not exactly what I'm after, because it blocks the UI and complicates things unnecessarily.

In my case I'm rather looking for a way to send an ajax request through the `HttpClient` similar to how you could do it with `jQuery` and `Content-Disposition`. The only way I've found out to work so far is to use `window.open(url)` which is probably not the best idea because it won't properly work with JWT authentication.

Comment: If you have an url, you can simply `window.location.href = __url__`

Comment: It looks like my entire life has been a lie! :D Seems to be working like a charm! Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Florian how is this even working?

Comment: @tftd how can asycnhronous call block UI? Maybe it's worth running outside Angular zone to avoid unnecessary change detection cycles?

Comment: @sergey : if the destination URL has correct headers (`Content-Disposition: attachment;`) the browser will download the file instead of navigating to the url.

Comment: @Sergey the here is not async / sync but rather user interaction which would need to be blocked to prevent the user from navigating away thus cancelling the download. :)

Comment: @tftd how can this even cancel the download? If you don't use `takeUntil` or manually dispose the observable it won't be ever destroyed if the subscription persists and observable is incomplete

Comment: You are correct - there is `takeUntil` and that's how it should be. I would rather have the browser deal with the file download (which could be 100+mb) than buffer it with JS and risk memory leaks.

Comment: Well then why not to create an anchor tag and emit click on it to download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to ask your browser to download a file :

```
const downloadFromUrl = '';
window.location.href = downloadFromUrl;
```

`window.location.href` is a property that returns the current URL location of the browser. As soon as you change this property, it will redirect the browser to the new URL location.

### EDIT :

[You can also use Fetch API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324014/download-file-from-url/57324389#57324389)
Note that this require the server to allow CORS policy.

Comment: However, this will cause url history problem when you go to some page and then press back I think

Comment: @Sergey No it doesn't. `window.location.href` will send an XHR request, if the response has `Content-Disposition: Attachment`, your browser won't even try to redirect you, it will understand he has to download a file. Hence, your history will remain clean.

Comment: I confirm @Florian's comment - history works fine. Thanks for posting your answer! :)